# Useless use of negative pattern binding (!~) in void context

Tags: perl

If both strings have spaces or neither has spaces, then do something.

```
my $with_spaces = $a =~ / / and $b =~ / /;
my $no_spaces = $a !~ / / and $b !~ / /;
if ($with_spaces or $no_spaces) {
    dosomething();
}
```

But this code gives an error:

> Useless use of negative pattern binding (!~) in void context.

Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: `and` has lower precedence than `=`. Try adding `(`...`)`

Comment: @jhnc This works.

Comment: `and` and `or` should only be used for flow control (e.g. `or next`, `or return`, `or die`, etc), or you get into precedence issues like this.

Comment: fyi, "useless use ... in void context" means you are evaluating an expression without side effects and discarding its result, something pointless, and therefore surely an error. (Regex matches have side effects (e.g. setting `$&`), which is why you didn't get a warning for the first line, but the result of the `!` in the second line is discarded.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lines:

```
my $with_spaces = $a =~ / / and $b =~ / /;
my $no_spaces = $a !~ / / and $b !~ / /;
```

are equivalent to:

```
(my $with_spaces = $a =~ / /) and ($b =~ / /);
(my $no_spaces = $a !~ / /) and ($b !~ / /);
```

Either use [`&&`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-And) instead of [`and`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-And), or add parentheses to change the [precedence](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity):

```
my $with_spaces = $a =~ / / && $b =~ / /;
my $no_spaces = ($a !~ / / and $b !~ / /);
```